# AVFAudio - Is it safe to perform file copy immediately after AVAudioRecorder.stop()

Tags: ios, swift

We start a voice recording via

```
self.avAudioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(
    url: self.recordingFileUrl, 
    settings: settings
)
self.avAudioRecorder.record()
```

At certain point, we will stop the recording via

```
self.avAudioRecorder.stop()
```

I was wondering, is it safe to perform file copy on `self.recordingFileUrl` immediately, after `self.avAudioRecorder.stop()`?

Is all recording data has been flushed to `self.recordingFileUrl` and `self.recordingFileUrl` file is closed properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems safer to perform file saving in [`audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_:successfully:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiorecorderdelegate/1388688-audiorecorderdidfinishrecording)

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705561

> It does seem to be synchronous, though in theory something
> could still fail at that point, so it is safer to use the delegate
> method audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_:successfully:), rather than
> make an assumption that the recording will always succeed after
> calling stop.